# Why cannot the function graph be drawn correctly after using variable replacement?

Tags: plotting

The following code can correctly draw the function image:

```
ClearAll["`*"];
f[x_] := 2 x^2 Sin[x]
xr = -5 <= x <= 5 || 9 <= x <= 10
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, -5, 15}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[x, -5 <= x <= 5 || 9 <= x <= 10]]
```

[image]

But replacing the range of x with the variable xr doesn't draw the picture correctly. Why?

```
ClearAll["`*"];
f[x_] := 2 x^2 Sin[x]
xr = -5 <= x <= 5 || 9 <= x <= 10
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, -5, 15}, RegionFunction -> Function[x, xr]]
```

get:

```
Plot::invregion: Function[x,xr][Identity[#1],Identity[#2]]& must be a Boolean function.
```

and the incorrect image:

[image]

The replacement part is:

```
xr = -5 <= x <= 5 || 9 <= x <= 10
```

The reason for using variable substitution is to reduce manual input. How can I use substitution to draw the function picture correctly?

Comment: `Function[x, Evaluate@xr]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_] := 2 x^2 Sin[x];
xr = -5 <= x <= 5 || 9 <= x <= 10;
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, -5, 15},RegionFunction-> Function[{x}, Evaluate @ xr]]
```

---

Function has "Attributes": {HoldAll}, so we need to manually evaluate it.

Answer (score 3):

A shorter alternative would be to define `xr` as a pure function

```
f[x_] := 2 x^2 Sin[x]

xr = -5 <= # <= 5 || 9 <= # <= 10 &;

Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 15}, RegionFunction -> xr]
```

[image]